# Rails 4 + Devise: After create user, create XYZ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I have a `User` model that gets created through Devise, and after it's creation, I would like to automatically create a new `Client` (another model in my app).  The new `Client`'s atrribute, `:user_id`, should be equal to the `:id` of the `User` that was just created.  I believe I need to use something like:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    after_create :create_client

    def create_client
        Client.create(:user_id, :id) # Not sure what should go here
    end 
end
```

Is this the correct way to accomplish this?  Also, if associations are important `Client belongs_to :user` and `User has_one :client`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an after_create callback in User model(user.rb), check [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) for more information on how to create has_one associations.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_save :add_client


   def add_client
     self.create_client(client_attribute1: value, client_attribute2: value)
   end
 end
```

Comment: Where are you getting `Contact`?  Is this supposed to be `User`?  Is this supposed to be the `Devise` `User` model?